# Proof about a property of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, second-countable

The result that I want to prove is the following:
Let's associate to each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ a number $r_{x}>0$. Then there is $M\in \mathbb{N}$ and a sequence $ \left( x_{n} \right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathbb{R} $ of distincts points of $\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$r_{x_{n}}>\frac{1}{M}, \ \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$$

It is clear that the result is true if the function $r$ is continuous, but I can't find a way to prove it in a general way. I know that I have to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. Can someone help me with a hint on how to attack this problem?

Comment: Consider the sets $\{x:r_x<1/n\}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Can they all be finite?

Comment: Isn't this trivially true? Just take $(x_n)$ to be a constant $x_n=x$ sequence and $M$ such that $1/M<r(x)$. Which exists by the fact that $r(x)>0$.

Comment: Yes! I have change my question. I wanted to say that there is a sequence of distinct points.

Comment: We have $\mathbb R = \{r_w|  r_w\in (0,\infty)\}$ and we can easily prove $(0,\infty)=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N} (\frac 1n, \infty)$ so we have $\mathbb R=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}\{r_w > \frac 1n\}$.   $\mathbb R$ is uncountable but $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}\{r_w > \frac 1n\}$ is a countable union of sets.  And countable union of finite sets is countable. But $\mathbb R$ is not countable, so at least one of the $\{r_w| r_w> \frac 1M\}$ is infinite.  Take your sequence from there.

Answer (score 0):

For each $M \in \mathbb N$ define
$$R_M = \bigl\{x \in \mathbb R \mid r_x > \frac{1}{M} \bigr\}
$$
Your statement is equivalent to saying that there exists $M \in \mathbb Z$ such that $R_M$ is infinite.

If not then $R_M$ is finite for all $M$. Using the sequence of inclusions
$$R_1 \subset R_2 \subset R_3 \subset \cdots \subset R_m \subset \cdots
$$
it follows, using finiteness of each $R_m$, that the set $\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb Z} R_m$ is countably infinite. But also $\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb Z} R_m = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid r_x > 0\} = \mathbb R$ which is uncountable.